# General formula for derivative of multiplication

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I'm struggling with numerical differentiation, Newton forward interpolation formula

To calculate my derivative i need to take derivative from the newton-forward interpolation polynom

So i need to take the derivatives of the next n polynomials in series:

$(t)' = 1$

$((t)(t-1))' = 2t-1$

$((t)(t-1)(t-2))' = 3t^{2}-6t+2$

$((t)(t-1)(t-2)(t-3))' = 4t^{3}-18t^{2}+22t-6$

$...$

$((t)(t-1)(t-2)...(t-n+1))' =  ?$

I cant figure out the general formula for it, is there any at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logarithmic derivative:
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = f \frac{df}{f dt} = f \frac{d\log f}{dt}.
$$
Now
$$
\left(
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (t-i)
\right)' =
\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (t-i)\right)
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{d\log (t-j)}{dt} = 
\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (t-i)\right)
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{t-j}.
$$

The expression might be simplified further if one puts the product into the sum:
$$
\left(
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (t-i)
\right)' =
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (t-i)}{t-j} = 
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \prod_{i=0, i\neq j}^{n-1} (t-i)
$$